# How to install modules for nodeJS on netbeans

Tags: mysql, node.js, netbeans

I'm trying to use extra modules with nodeJS and netbeans, however when I try to search for the modules on netbeans it seems to simply hangup forever.

Any idea what is going on? I already had the modules installed with npm install and command line, then I right click libraries on netbeans and the search hangs.

The installed modules are mysql & aws-sdk, and I'm using windows 7, 64 bits. Also on the Tools > Options > General > Proxy definitions, there is a "Test Connnection" button. If I click on it, I get a green check saying connection is OK.

Thanks

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Check if the option which you have selected is 'No Proxy', for some reason for me it was pre-selected the option 'Use System Proxy Settings' and then when i updated it failed. Once i changed it to 'No Proxy', the update installation worked.

In Netbeans, Go into Tools-> Options -> Miscellaneous -> Node.js and see that you have configured the settings properly.

see this for more info, it is a plugin for NodeJS projects: http://timboudreau.com/blog/NetBeans_Tools_for_Node_js/read